# VirtueMart Custom Checkout steps

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

i need help editing VirteuMart 2.0.10 checkout steps. Instead of the default stuff, all i need is to collect user information such as name, address, phone number etc along with the details of items in the shopping cart. Then display information to the user about how they can payment via a local mobile money solution.

I need it to be this way because there are currently no VM plugins or extensions for the said payment solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but if you are looking to remove the "checkout bar" with the 1-2-3-4 steps on checkout, this is simple to do in settings.

Go to Admin > Configuration. Select the "Checkout" tab. Unselect the "Enable the Checkout Bar" option, and select the options directly below that you wish to enable upon checkout.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That is not exactly what i wanted but it has solved my problem all the same. Thank you very much.